# Unable to put two content_tags in a single helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why would:

**app/helpers/application_helper.rb**

```
def my_test
  content_tag(:p, "One")
  content_tag(:p, "Two")
end
```

**app/views/main/index.html.erb**

```
<%= my_test %>
```

result in:

```
<p>Two</p>
```

and not:

```
<p>One</p>
<p>Two</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `+` between 2 `content_tag()` method:

```
def my_test
  content_tag(:p, "One") + \
  content_tag(:p, "Two")
end
```

The Ruby returns only a last expression from the method. To return all desired html you should add one to another.